# Safely defining variables for public callback functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, callback, this, google-closure-library, youtube-javascript-api

I am working with the YouTube iFrame API to embed a number of videos on a page. Documentation here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Requirements

In summary, you load the API asynchronously using the following snippet:

```
 var tag = document.createElement('script');
 tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
 var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

Once loaded, the API fires the predefined callback function `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady`.

For additional context: I am defining a library file for this in Google Closure. I am providing a namespace: `goog.provide('yt.video');`

I then use `goog.exportSymbol` so that the API can find the function. That all works fine.

My challenge is that I would like to pass 2 variables to the callback function. Is there any way to do this without defining these 2 variables in the context of the `window` object?

```
goog.provide('yt.video');

goog.require('goog.dom');

yt.video = function(videos, locales) {
  this.videos = videos;
  this.captionLocales = locales;

  this.init();
};

yt.video.prototype.init = function() {
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
};

/*
 * Callback function fired when YT API is ready
 * This is exported using goog.exportSymbol in another file and
 * is being fired by the API properly.
 */
 yt.video.prototype.onPlayerReady = function(videos, locales) {
    window.console.log('this :' + this); //logs window
    window.console.log('this.videos : ' + this.videos); //logs undefined
    /*
     * Video settings from Django variable
     */
    for(i=0; i<this.videos.length; i++) {
      var playerEvents = {};
      var embedVars = {};

      var el = this.videos[i].el;
      var playerVid = this.videos[i].vid;
      var playerWidth = this.videos[i].width;
      var playerHeight = this.videos[i].height;
      var captionLocales = this.videos[i].locales;
      if(this.videos[i].playerVars)
        var embedVars = this.videos[i].playerVars;
      }
      if(this.videos[i].events) {
        var playerEvents = this.videos[i].events;
      }

      /*
       * Show captions by default
       */
      if(goog.array.indexOf(captionLocales, 'es') >= 0) {
        embedVars.cc_load_policy = 1;
      };

      new YT.Player(el, {
        height: playerHeight,
        width: playerWidth,
        videoId: playerVid,
        events: playerEvents,
        playerVars: embedVars
    });
 };
```

};

To intialize this, I am currently using the following within a self-executing anonymous function:

```
  var videos = [
    {"vid": "video_id", "el": "player-1", "width": 640, "height": 390, "locales": ["es", "fr"], "events": {"onStateChange": stateChanged}}, 
    {"vid": "video_id", "el": "player-2", "locales": ["es", "fr"], "width": 640, "height": 390}
  ];

  var locales = ['es'];

  var videoTemplate = new yt.video(videos, locales);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about defining `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady` as a global function like how the API expects it and then call your `onPlayerReady` method from inside that function? Code sample:

```
window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function () {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    args.push(videos, locales);
    videoTemplate.onPlayerReady.apply(videoTemplate, args);
};
```

And you modify the signature of onPlayerReady method to accept arguments in the same order

Comment: Thanks for your response! This is a clever idea. If I wanted to avoid modifying window for this, can you think of any other solution? I guess I am stuck with this approach if the API assumes the window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady, correct?

Comment: Yeah, I think if the API expects the definition like that, there might not be another approach that I can think of. If you're worried about polluting the global namespace (window in this case), you can always nullify the onYouTubePlayerAPIReady after it is done with the job, i.e, window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = null as the last line inside onYouTubePlayerAPIReady method

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question:

> My challenge is that I would like to pass 2 variables to the callback function. Is there any way to do this without defining these 2 variables in the context of the window object?

Yes, there are ways to provide data to a callback function without using global variables. However, before looking at the callback function, the YouTube API has the following requirement:

> [In addition, any HTML page that contains the YouTube player must implement a JavaScript function named **`onYouTubePlayerReady`**. The API will call this function when the player is fully loaded and the API is ready to receive calls.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Requirements)

The YouTube API [examples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Examples) add event listeners within the **`onYouTubePlayerReady`** function as shown here:

```
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  var player;
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    width: 1280,
    height: 720,
    videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onPlaybackQualityChange': onPlayerPlaybackQualityChange,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
      'onError': onPlayerError
    }
  });
}
```

---

It appears that your example callback function `yt.video.prototype.onPlayerReady` is intended to be an event listener for the YouTube API event `onReady` emitted by a YouTube `YT.Player` object. The API docs indicate that event listeners are added either when constructing the `YT.Player` object or added using the `addEventListener` function (the [Closure Library](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/) alternative is [`goog.events.listen`](http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/trunk/closure/goog/events/events.js#121)).

Since the `yt.video.prototype.onPlayerReady` event listener needs to "listen" for the `onReady` event emitted from a YouTube `YT.Player` object, it would be circular to construct new `YT.Player` instances within the event listener `yt.video.prototype.onPlayerReady` intended to listen for an event emitted by a `YT.Player` instance.

Getting back to the original question of providing data to callback functions without using global variables, you cannot pass arbitrary function arguments to an event listener (for example, in the original code sample above, `yt.video.prototype.onPlayerReady` must accept an `Event` object as its first argument rather than a `videos` array). However, the event listener `yt.video.prototype.onPlayerReady` can be used as a callback function and still access the state of `yt.video` instance objects as long as it is *bound* to instances of `yt.video`.

One way to bind the `this` argument to a specific object is with the [Closure Library](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/) function [goog.bind(functionToCall, selfObject, var_args)](http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/trunk/closure/goog/base.js#1031). The `yt.video` constructor could be modified as follows:

```
goog.provide('yt.video');

goog.require('goog.dom');

/**
 * @constructor
 */
yt.video = function(videos, locales) {
  this.videos = videos;
  this.captionLocales = locales;

  this.onPlayerReadyListener = goog.bind(this.onPlayerReady, this);

  this.init();
};

yt.video.prototype.init = function() {
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
};

/*
 * Callback function fired when YT API is ready
 * This is exported using goog.exportSymbol in another file and
 * is being fired by the API properly.
 */
yt.video.prototype.onPlayerReady = function(event) {
  // Logs [object Object]
  window.console.log('this :' + this);

  // Logs [object Object],[object Object]
  window.console.log('this.videos : ' + this.videos); 

  event.target.playVideo();
};
```

Then the bound event listener could be added to a `YT.Player` object as follows:

```
var myVideoObject = new yt.video(videos, locales);

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  var player;
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    width: 1280,
    height: 720,
    videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw',
    events: {
      'onReady': myVideoObject.onPlayerReadyListener
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I had given bind a try actually. this.onPlayerReadyListener = goog.bind(this.onPlayerReady, this); does not seem to work. this.video is still undefined from within yt.video.prototype.onPlayerReady. Any idea why?

Comment: @djreed: See updated code sample above based on testing in Chrome. Inside `yt.video.prototype.onPlayerReady`, `this.videos` now successfully logs `[object Object],[object Object]` instead of `undefined`. The event listener for `onStateChange` has been changed to `yt.onPlayerStateChange`. Also, as a matter of style, it might be good to use a different namespace for your library (`yt` versus `YT` could be confusing).

Comment: Can you explain why you've added the function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady? This function is already defined as yt.video.prototype.onPlayerReady

Comment: @djreed I updated the answer to explain the YouTube API requirement of defining a function named `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady` as well as clarifying the mechanics of the event handler.